# Commercial C# chart controls - cross technology

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

As part of a project, I need to evaluate some commercial **C# chart components**.
I am looking for feature rich components that support zooming/panning, can handle real time updates and maybe even produce events for things like double clicking on a point.

I'd prefer components that can be used across technologies in case I need to move from WinForms to WPF.

Looking around stackoverflow and googling a bit I have the following list:

- [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/)
- [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)
- [Visifire](http://visifire.com/)
- [SilverLight](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)
- [YWorks/YFiles](http://www.yworks.com/)
- [VisiBlox](http://www.visiblox.com/)
- [SoftwareFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/)
- [Gigasoft](http://www.gigasoft.com/)

**Please Note:**
I'm only looking for suggestions of component producers here, I'm not looking for opinions on which is best as I will need to decide that based on some testing strategy to ensure the right fit for my solution.

Comment: my input is that you should not compare apples with grapes. ChartFX of SoftwareFX costs all alone way more than the whole DevXpress or Telerik full component libraries, XtraChart of DevXpress is a very valid product but can't compete with ChartFX which is alone flagship product of SoftwareFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also  one very well supported called [xceed](http://xceed.com/)

Look for "charts" on the website.

Comment: This is what I was after.  Exceed looks great, I'll add it to my testing list.  Didn't previously know about it

Comment: we use it for over 4 years now in our products

Answer (score 2):

to further elaborate my previous comment above,

my suggestion is to check the online demo of DevXpress XtraChart (works basically everywhere: WinForms, WebForms, SL, WPF, ASP.NET MVC...).

if you feel it satisfies all your needs you could go for it, I used it and I am very happy with it and with the whole DevXpress product suite.

Telerik version seems to have much less chart types, especially in the MVC implementation.

ChartFX of SoftwareFX is the most complete and powerful, result of years of investment and development from that company and it locates itself way above all the others.